# Everything showed good, except the tabs. (HTML,CSS,JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, xhtml

Iam working on a website and I dont have any clue why the tabs doesnt work when I upload the website. Because when I view the website normal it does work perfectly.
By the way: The tabs are working with a jquery script.

This is the website URL: http://bmvisuals.poshh.nl/

Greetings.

Edit: I mean some of the tabs doesnt appear.

Comment: the tabs work but slow in safari

Comment: What do you mean by they don't work? What doesn't work? Clicking on them? Or do they not even appear? They work for me.

Comment: Also, some code would be nice. :)

Comment: Everything works perfectly fine in my Opera. By the way, you write that you have valid XHTML, and it's not, so I advice you to check it.

Comment: @Malcolm

Thnx for the hint. A time ago I checked it and it was oke. I will check it again and fix it ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your About me tab does not show up because your server is case sensitive.

Aboutme.jpg != Aboutme.JPG

You should check out [CSS Sprites](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/04/27/the-mystery-of-css-sprites-techniques-tools-and-tutorials/).  There is a flicker when you hover over a tab (the first time) because the browser has to load the hover image. With CSS Sprites an image map is used and all the images are loaded at once so the hover is seamless.

As an aside, your site does not scroll vertically. When my window is smaller than your site, the bottom gets cut off and there is no way for me to see it.

Comment: Thank you so much!
Also thank you about telling me the CSS sprites.

The reason why I dont let the window scroll is that, when I do that my whole site fails. Look at this: http://img218.imageshack.us/img218/8053/failkle.png

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, nice site. Secondly your tabs are totally borked for me. I am using Linux Ubuntu and Firefox 3. Not sure about the fix though. Just thought I would mention it.

Answer (score 0):

Using Firebug, I see some resources give a 404 error:

- http://bmvisuals.poshh.nl/Scripts/Lightbox/images/lightbox-ico-loading.gif
- http://bmvisuals.poshh.nl/Scripts/Images/PhotoGallery/PhotoGalleryContainerBackground.png
- http://bmvisuals.poshh.nl/Images/Tabs/Aboutme.jpg
- http://bmvisuals.poshh.nl/Images/Tabs/HomeActive.png

On a side note, the page doesn't work if javascript is disabled. I would suggest using the noscript tag to show a message saying javascript is required. The other option is to make the page work without javascript.

Comment: I do use firebug but I don't get any clue about it :S

Who has disabled javascript now a days?

Comment: Under the "Net" tab in Firebug it will show all of the requests Firefox makes for that page.

I have javascript disabled. :) I use the NoScript plugin for Firefox for two reasons; it can prevent some types of attacks (like cross site scripting), and it prevents webpages from doing random crazy things. Most sites work just fine without javascript.

A minority of people have javascript disabled, so using the noscript tag should be good enough.